# Create a new column on a pandas pivot_table with multiindex

Tags: pandas, pivot-table, multiple-columns, concatenation, multi-index

This seems so simple I can't believe I'm pulling my hairs.
I have a pivot_table like this

```
Name      income          expenses
         2015  2016       2015  2016
Joe Doe     2     4          5     7
Jane Doe    2     4          5     7
Doe Joe     2     4          5     7
Doe Jane    2     4          5     7
```

I simply want to add a calculated column  profit_loss = (income - expenses)
I thought it would be something like:

```
 df['profit_loss'] = df['income'] - df['expenses]
```

I only get errors.

Without having to write a lot of code or preparation to the base table that creates this pivot_table, is there an easier way to deal with `MultiIndexes` on a pandas pivot_table ?

Comment: can you [post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39581185/edit) an output of `df.to_dict()` so it would be easier for us to build your multi-index DF?

Answer (score 1):

You can use first [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html), because error:

> KeyError: 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (2), lexsort depth (0)'

Then use [slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers) and last [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) `a` to original `df`:

```
df.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)

idx = pd.IndexSlice
a  = df.loc[:,idx['income',:]] - df.loc[:,idx['expenses',:]].values
#rename column name
a = a.rename(columns={'income':'profit_loss'})
print (a)
         profit_loss     
                2015 2016
Joe Doe           -3   -3
Jane Doe          -3   -3
Doe Joe           -3   -3
Doe Jane          -3   -3

df1 = pd.concat([df,a], axis=1)
print (df1)
         expenses      income      profit_loss     
             2015 2016   2015 2016        2015 2016
Joe Doe         5    7      2    4          -3   -3
Jane Doe        5    7      2    4          -3   -3
Doe Joe         5    7      2    4          -3   -3
Doe Jane        5    7      2    4          -3   -3
```

Answer (score 1):

Without having to sort, couldn't you assign to a new column within your multi-index, something like the following:

```
df['profit_loss','2015'] = df['income','2015'] - df['expenses','2015']
df['profit_loss','2016'] = df['income','2016'] - df['expenses','2016']
```

This could get messy with a lot of years though, but I imagine then you could create a function and loop through the years if you needed to do this repetitively.